# Reduce sessions' log size

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

We have a session that process a millions of rows. The problem is that it creates a huge log with two main issues:

1. Log size makes it hard to handle and analize.
2. Log size slows down the process (we guess, since the log is >55 GB).

There is a way to reduce the size of the log? We don't need to know every time the application does a commit for instance.

Comment: what should be the expected behaviour ? what do you find most useful ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the log level to **Terse**, which will get your log size to minimal.  (setting in session configuration).

The downside of setting **Terse** is that you wont get lot of information when something goes wrong and you want to find something in log.

To change the log level:

- Open your session (double click on it in your workflow, unless its a reusable session)
- Go to the *Config Object* tab
- Select appropriate value from the *Override tracing* drop-down list (it allows you to control the logging level of the session as a whole; if you want, you can override the individual components' log level in the *Components* tab)

Comment: Where can I find log leves in Session Configuration? I am in the Workflow Designer 9.1 and looking into Task > Session Configuration but I cannot find nothing about log level.